# Docker Image Download with download-frozen-image-v2.sh on Windows

Tags: bash, docker, jq

I am working on downloading a Docker Image on an internet-connected Windows machine that does not have (and cannot have) Docker installed on it, to transfer to an non-internet-connected Linux machine that does have Docker. I'm using `git-bash` to run [download-frozen-image-v2.sh](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/download-frozen-image-v2.sh). Everything is working as expected until the script begins to download the final layer of any given image. On the final layer the json file is being returned empty. Through echo statements, I'm able to see that everything is working flawlessly until *lines 119-142*

```
jq "$addJson + ." > "$dir/$layerId/json" <<-'EOJSON'
                {
                    "created": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                    "container_config": {
                        "Hostname": "",
                        "Domainname": "",
                        "User": "",
                        "AttachStdin": false,
                        "AttachStdout": false,
                        "AttachStderr": false,
                        "Tty": false,
                        "OpenStdin": false,
                        "StdinOnce": false,
                        "Env": null,
                        "Cmd": null,
                        "Image": "",
                        "Volumes": null,
                        "WorkingDir": "",
                        "Entrypoint": null,
                        "OnBuild": null,
                        "Labels": null
                    }
                }
            EOJSON
```

Only on the final layer, this code is resulting in an empty json file, which in-turn creates an error in *line 173*

`jq --raw-output "$imageOldConfig + del(.history, .rootfs)" "$dir/$configFile" > "$dir/$imageId/json"`

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '+', expecting $end (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
 + del(.history, .rootfs)
jq: 1 compile error
```

**Update**

---

**Exact steps to replicate**

Perform on Windows 10 computer.

1) Install scoop for Windows https://scoop.sh/

2) *in Powershell* `scoop install git curl jq go tar`

3) `git-bash`

4) *in git-bash* `curl -o download-frozen-image-v2.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moby/moby/master/contrib/download-frozen-image-v2.sh`

5) `bash download-frozen-image-vs.sh ubuntu ubuntu:latest`

The above will result in the aforementioned error.

---

in response to @peak below

The command I'm using is `bash download-frozen-image-v2.sh ubuntu ubuntu:latest` which should download 5 layers. The first 4 download flawlessly, it is only the last layer that fails. I tried this process for several other images, and it always fails on the final layer.

**addJson:**

```
{ id: "ee6b1042efee4fb07d2fe1a5079ce498567e6f5ac849413f0e623d4582da5bc9", parent: "80a2fb00dfe137a28c24fbc39fde656650cd68028d612e6f33912902d887b108" }
```

**dir/configFile:**

```
ubuntu/113a43faa1382a7404681f1b9af2f0d70b182c569aab71db497e33fa59ed87e6.json
```

**dir/configFile contents:**

```
{
"architecture": "amd64",
  "config": {
    "Hostname": "",
    "Domainname": "",
    "User": "",
    "AttachStdin": false,
    "AttachStdout": false,
    "AttachStderr": false,
    "Tty": false,
    "OpenStdin": false,
    "StdinOnce": false,
    "Env": [
      "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
    ],
    "Cmd": [
      "/bin/bash"
    ],
    "ArgsEscaped": true,
    "Image": "sha256:c2775c69594daa3ee360d8e7bbca93c65d9c925e89bd731f12515f9bf8382164",
    "Volumes": null,
    "WorkingDir": "",
    "Entrypoint": null,
    "OnBuild": null,
    "Labels": null
  },
  "container": "6713e927cc43b61a4ce3950a69907336ff55047bae9393256e32613a54321c70",
  "container_config": {
    "Hostname": "6713e927cc43",
    "Domainname": "",
    "User": "",
    "AttachStdin": false,
    "AttachStdout": false,
    "AttachStderr": false,
    "Tty": false,
    "OpenStdin": false,
    "StdinOnce": false,
    "Env": [
      "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
    ],
    "Cmd": [
      "/bin/sh",
      "-c",
      "#(nop) ",
      "CMD [\"/bin/bash\"]"
    ],
    "ArgsEscaped": true,
    "Image": "sha256:c2775c69594daa3ee360d8e7bbca93c65d9c925e89bd731f12515f9bf8382164",
    "Volumes": null,
    "WorkingDir": "",
    "Entrypoint": null,
    "OnBuild": null,
    "Labels": {}
  },
  "created": "2018-06-05T21:20:54.310450149Z",
  "docker_version": "17.06.2-ce",
  "history": [
    {
      "created": "2018-06-05T21:20:51.286433694Z",
      "created_by": "/bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:28c0771e44ff530dba3f237024acc38e8ec9293d60f0e44c8c78536c12f13a0b in / "
    },
    {
      "created": "2018-06-05T21:20:52.045074543Z",
      "created_by": "/bin/sh -c set -xe \t\t&& echo '#!/bin/sh' > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d \t&& echo 'exit 101' >> /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d \t&& chmod +x /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d \t\t&& dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl \t&& cp -a /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d /sbin/initctl \t&& sed -i 's/^exit.*/exit 0/' /sbin/initctl \t\t&& echo 'force-unsafe-io' > /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/docker-apt-speedup \t\t&& echo 'DPkg::Post-Invoke { \"rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true\"; };' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean \t&& echo 'APT::Update::Post-Invoke { \"rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true\"; };' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean \t&& echo 'Dir::Cache::pkgcache \"\"; Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache \"\";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean \t\t&& echo 'Acquire::Languages \"none\";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-no-languages \t\t&& echo 'Acquire::GzipIndexes \"true\"; Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order:: \"gz\";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-gzip-indexes \t\t&& echo 'Apt::AutoRemove::SuggestsImportant \"false\";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-autoremove-suggests"
    },
    {
      "created": "2018-06-05T21:20:52.712120056Z",
      "created_by": "/bin/sh -c rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*"
    },
    {
      "created": "2018-06-05T21:20:53.405342638Z",
      "created_by": "/bin/sh -c sed -i 's/^#\\s*\\(deb.*universe\\)$/\\1/g' /etc/apt/sources.list"
    },
    {
      "created": "2018-06-05T21:20:54.091704323Z",
      "created_by": "/bin/sh -c mkdir -p /run/systemd && echo 'docker' > /run/systemd/container"
    },
    {
      "created": "2018-06-05T21:20:54.310450149Z",
      "created_by": "/bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD [\"/bin/bash\"]",
      "empty_layer": true
    }
  ],
  "os": "linux",
  "rootfs": {
    "type": "layers",
    "diff_ids": [
      "sha256:db9476e6d963ed2b6042abef1c354223148cdcdbd6c7416c71a019ebcaea0edb",
      "sha256:3a89e0d8654e098e949764b1cb23018e27f299b0931c5fd41c207d610ff356c4",
      "sha256:904d60939c360b5f528b886c1b534855a008f9a7fd411d4977e09aa7de74c834",
      "sha256:a20a262b87bd8a00717f3b30c001bcdaf0fd85d049e6d10500597caa29c013c5",
      "sha256:b6f13d447e00fba3b9bd10c1e5c6697e913462f44aa24af349bfaea2054e32f4"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any help in figuring out what is occurring here would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please try to follow the [mcve] guidelines more closely.  In particular, it seems we need to know the contents of $addJson and $dir/$configFile

Comment: @peak I have edited the question with the information you requested.

Comment: This seems to be related to the length of the path to the files. The windows path for example where it works for me if I were to trim the end of the hash is `C:\Users\jmercado\AppData\Local\Temp\frozen\ubuntu\ee6b1042efee4fb07d2fe1a\json` which is exactly 79 characters. At 80, nothing happens, and any more segfaults. This might just be coincidence that it's 80 because when I try to install on shorter paths (`./download-frozen-image-v2.sh /c/f/u ubuntu:latest`), it still fails. Again, I was only able to open the file if the folder name was `ee6b1042efee4fb07d2fe1a` at the longest.

Comment: Hmm, it seems like any directory in the path must be at most 25 characters otherwise it will segfault.

Comment: @JeffMercado I tried your solution, and I'm still seeing the same failure. I've made sure every directory and file in the path is at most 25 characters (`newConfigFile=$(echo $imageId | cut -c1-25)` etc.), and it is still failing for me. I will keep looking into this, and seeif I can get a success out of it. Thank you for your insights so far. I'm going to see if I replicate your 79 character path, if I can get a success.

Comment: I think it's actually the 25+ folder in the path that's causing issue. File names are no problem apparently, it's the folder that's causing problems. I was going to run more tests but ran out of time yesterday.

Comment: @JeffMercado I find the script succeeds if I trim to 23 characters. However, that introduces the problem that Docker does not successfully import the image on the other end.

Comment: @JeffMercado it seems you are correct in identifying the issue https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1205

Comment: I was just about to link to that. :) I ran a few tests to test some theories I had and couldn't draw any hard conclusions. https://gist.github.com/JeffreyMercado/f7debf1a5ae25d21398143b2110e8b68 In the "input filename" tests; 1, 2, 3, 4, and 7 segfaults. This didn't match up with what I thought as I would have expected the longer names to fail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173831/discussion-between-sosukeinu-and-jeff-mercado).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't tell you why this happens but it appears to be a problem with how jq parses the input file. It's segfaulting when reading the file. It's a [known issue](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1205) in the windows builds where the problem is triggered by the length of the paths to the files.

Fortunately, there is a way around this issue by modifying the script to [go against all conventional wisdom](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) and `cat` the file to jq.

The script isn't utilizing jq very well and builds some of the json manually so some additional fixes would be needed. It will have errors regarding `INVALID_CHARACTER` when parsing. It's probably a manifestation of [this issue](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1219) since the script is manually building a lot of the jq programs.

I put up a gist with the [updated file](https://gist.github.com/JeffreyMercado/abf99779d42f9017d358bed9901daf55) that at least doesn't error out, check to see if it works as expected.

Changes start at line [172](https://gist.github.com/JeffreyMercado/abf99779d42f9017d358bed9901daf55#file-download-frozen-image-v2-sh-L172) and [342](https://gist.github.com/JeffreyMercado/abf99779d42f9017d358bed9901daf55#file-download-frozen-image-v2-sh-L342).

The way it builds the manifest is just messy. I've cleaned it up a bit removing all the string interpolations instead passing all parameters in as arguments to jq.

```
# munge the top layer image manifest to have the appropriate image configuration for older daemons
local imageOldConfig="$(cat "$dir/$imageId/json" | jq --raw-output --compact-output '{ id: .id } + if .parent then { parent: .parent } else {} end')"
cat "$dir/$configFile" | jq --raw-output "$imageOldConfig + del(.history, .rootfs)" > "$dir/$imageId/json"

local manifestJsonEntry="$(
    jq --raw-output --compact-output -n \
        --arg configFile "$configFile" \
        --arg repoTags "${image#library\/}:$tag" \
        --argjson layers "$(IFS=$'\n'; jq --arg a "${layerFiles[*]}" -n '$a | split("\n")')" \
        '{
            Config: $configFile,
            RepoTags: [ $repoTags ],
            Layers: $layers
        }'
)"
```

Comment: There are plenty of other opportunities to clean up the script. For instance the use of the `imageOldConfig` variable could be completely removed doing some rewrites. And in many cases, the `--raw-output` option is just unnecessary. But I only opted for doing minimal changes.

Comment: Thank you so much. works great. The more I dig into jq, the more I see what you mean about clean up.

Comment: FYI, I made a slight modification to how the arrays are built in this post and the gist. It probably won't be an issue in practice but if any of the file paths had spaces in them, the arrays would get messed up. Changed to use newlines as delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

(1) I have verified that using bash, the sequence:

```
addJson='{ id: "ee6b1042efee4fb07d2fe1a5079ce498567e6f5ac849413f0e623d4582da5bc9",
  parent: "80a2fb00dfe137a28c24fbc39fde656650cd68028d612e6f33912902d887b108" }'

jq "$addJson + ." configFile > layerId.json
```

succeeds, where configFile has the contents shown in the updated question.

(2) Similarly, I have verified that the following also succeeds:

```
imageOldConfig="$(jq --raw-output --compact-output '{ id: .id } + if .parent then { parent: .parent } else {} end' layerId.json)"

jq --raw-output "$imageOldConfig + del(.history, .rootfs)" <<-'EOJSON'
<JSON as in the question>
EOJSON
```

where `<JSON as in the question>` stands for the JSON shown in the question.

(3) In general, it is not a good idea to pass shell $-variables into jq programs by shell string interpolation.

For example, rather than writing:

```
jq --raw-output "$imageOldConfig + del(.history, .rootfs)"
```

it would be much better to write something like:

```
jq --raw-output --argjson imageOldConfig "$imageOldConfig" '
    $imageOldConfig + del(.history, .rootfs)'
```

Comment: unfortunately, this does not solve my issue. I still receive an issue an error, `invalid JSON text passed to --argjson` because `$imageOldConfig` is empty, and the final layer json file continues to be empty as well. I've added exact steps to replicate to the question. I have tested and the issue exists on 3 different computers.